# In jsTree I get data.rslt as undefined

Tags: jquery, json, jstree

Using jsTree, I get data.rslt undefined when trying to read the data object.

Here is my jQuery, creating a tree, loading the JSON and it should output the data.rslt object to the console when loaded.

```
$(function () {
    $("#demo1").jstree({ 
        "plugins" : [ "themes","json_data","ui", "crrm" ],
        "json_data" : {
            "ajax" : {
                "url" : "categorytreejson.asp"
            }
        },
        "ui" : {
            "initially_select" : [ "root" ]
        }
    });

    $("#demo1").bind("loaded.jstree", function (e, data) {
        console.log(data.rslt)
    });
});
```

Here is the JSON data

```
{"data": "root", "attr": {"id": "root"}, "children": [{"data": "Photography", "attr": {"id": "Photography"}, "children": [{"data": "Lenses", "attr": {"id": "Lenses"}, "children": [{"data": "Telephoto", "attr": {"id": "Telephoto"}},{"data": "Macro", "attr": {"id": "Macro"}},{"data": "Other", "attr": {"id": "Other"}}]}]}]}
```

The resulting HTML

```
<li class="jstree-last jstree-open" id="root"><ins class="jstree-icon">&nbsp;</ins><a class="" href="#"><ins class="jstree-icon">&nbsp;</ins>root</a><ul style=""><li class="jstree-closed" id="Photography"><ins class="jstree-icon">&nbsp;</ins><a class="" href="#"><ins class="jstree-icon">&nbsp;</ins>Photography</a><ul><li class="jstree-last jstree-closed" id="Lenses"><ins class="jstree-icon">&nbsp;</ins><a href="#"><ins class="jstree-icon">&nbsp;</ins>Lenses</a><ul><li class="jstree-leaf" id="Telephoto"><ins class="jstree-icon">&nbsp;</ins><a href="#"><ins class="jstree-icon">&nbsp;</ins>Telephoto</a></li><li class="jstree-leaf" id="Macro"><ins class="jstree-icon">&nbsp;</ins><a href="#"><ins class="jstree-icon">&nbsp;</ins>Macro</a></li><li class="jstree-last jstree-leaf" id="Other"><ins class="jstree-icon">&nbsp;</ins><a href="#"><ins class="jstree-icon">&nbsp;</ins>Other</a></li></ul></li></ul></li></li></ul></li></ul></li>
```

And the data object in Firebug.

```
args: []
inst: Object { data={...}, get_settings=function(), _get_settings=function(), more...}
rlbk: false
rslt: undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some events will not populate the `data.rslt` object.
As of the [jsTree core documentation](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/core):

**data structure**:

```
{ 
   "inst" : /* the actual tree instance */, 
   "args" : /* arguments passed to the function */, 
   "rslt" : /* any data the function passed to the event */, 
   "rlbk" : /* an optional rollback object - it is not always present */
}
```

In particular, the `loaded.jstree` event will have an empty data.rslt because no additional data was passed to the function.

Other events like `create.jstree` or `rename.jstree` will have the data.rslt populated.

I hope it's more clear to you now :-)

Comment: Thank you, your right and I have it working now.
I guess I should've been reading a bit more.

Comment: I've spent a couple of hours on this problem now, and this answer doesn't really clear up anything for me. I'm following the ajax demo from here: http://www.jstree.com/demo/open_close and am getting an error about no addBack function. Plus, the 'n' object passed to the ajax data function has no attr("id") value, so I have to use this convoluted menagerie to get the id of the clicked item: $(n[0]).find("a").attr("id").